# Set text color to active state on dropdown navigation

Tags: html, css

I have created a navigation where you can hover over an element and it executes a dropdown list with more choices to choose from.

The problem I'm having is when I choose an element and then hover over the sub menu the main element color will not stay active. I tried adding an active class, but dosen't seem to be working.

```
a:active {
    color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/4c6Vj/1/) That will better explain the problem I'm having. If someone wouldn't mind checking it out for me. That would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is that the link's color is set when you hover over the link itself (the `a` element). What you need to do is make it so that the link's color changes when you hover over the element containing the link and its submenus so that when you're hovering over the submenus, you're still hovering over the containing element (the `li` element)

The child selector `>` is used here so that the submenu links are not also affected when you're hovering over the parent link. Be aware that IE6 does not understand `>` selectors; so you will have to give the child `a` elements classes if you want them to work that far back.

CSS:

```
.sf-menu li:hover > a {
    color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4c6Vj/4/)

Comment: 1+ I thought the OP wanted the `:active` state to work.. didn't even notice the dropdown issue.

Comment: Hmmm I took your advice and checked out your Fiddle, but when I hover over the subitems the top category text still doesn't change to white?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you visited this link and not JoshC's previous link? http://jsfiddle.net/4c6Vj/4/ If you're sure, what browser are you using? Also, are you referring to when it is in smartphone "mode"?

Comment: Weird it works now. Must have been a cache issue or something. Anyways thanks for the help. It works now! Thank you!